# Speech recognition with file as input

Tags: delphi, speech-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [speech recognition from audio file instead of microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055347/speech-recognition-from-audio-file-instead-of-microphone)

How can someone perform speech recognition with a file (.wav or .mp3) as input and using Delphi ?

I want to use an audio file as input rather than the microphone.

Comment: Close.  Not only is this question a duplicate, it's a duplicate of a question asked by this same poster, with an accepted answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055347/speech-recognition-from-audio-file-instead-of-microphone

Answer (score 2):

See [Delphi and SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021490/delphi-and-sapi), [Vista Speech Recognition in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274255/vista-speech-recognition-in-delphi), [Speech recognition not working well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053217/speech-recognition-not-working-well), and [Speech Synthesis & Speech Recognition Using SAPI 5.1](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29583).